# DirectX Compile Shader from Memory?

Tags: c++, directx, shader, directx-11

Using shaders compiled from files like this works:

```
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(filename, NULL, NULL, "main", "vs_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, NULL, 
                   &vertexShaderBuffer, &errorMessage, NULL);
```

But if I replace the above line with this one:

```
D3DX11CompileFromMemory(vs, strlen(vs), NULL, NULL, NULL, "main", "vs_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, NULL, 
                   &vertexShaderBuffer, &errorMessage, NULL);
```

While `vs` is a char* of the shader file (if I print `vs` out using `std::cout`, it prints correctly).

It just crashes at that line...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2021/08/11/directwrite-over-d3d11/ has an example of using `D3DX11CompileFromMemory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3DX APIs are deprecated, you should use the D3DCompile APIs instead from `D3DCompiler.h`. Mostly the same things with D3DX11 replaced by D3D so transition is simple.

Edit your message with at least a callstack or output log because wihtout more information, it is hard to be more specific on an answer.

Comment: Ok, my compiler (MSVC++ 2012) can't find those D3DCompile functions (only `D3DCompile` but not `D3DCompileFromFile`). I included `D3Dcompiler.h`. What else do I have to do?

Comment: compiler or linker ? Could you be a bit more verbose on the errors you have, it will help us to answer something useful.

Comment: It doesn't compile! I get this message, when trying to compile:
`error C3861: 'D3DCompileFromMemory': identifier not found`

Comment: Because the default way is from memory now, it is just `D3DCompile`. Here the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, thank you. So if I want to compile a shader from a file, I have to read it in myself!?

Comment: Did you ever try to open header files or documentation ? d3dcompiler.h contains a function declaration `D3DCompileFromFile` and you just have to google it to find the documentation of each arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Sorry for my stupidness, but it doesn't find those functions like I said before... `error C3861: 'D3DCompileFromMemory': identifier not found` AND `error C3861: 'D3DCompileFromFile': identifier not found`

Comment: I opened the `D3Dcompiler.h` header but there was neither a `D3DCompileFromFile`, nor a `D3DCompileFromMemory`. But in the documentation it says, that I have to include `D3Dcompiler.h` to use `D3DCompileFromFile` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446872(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What you say is really surprising, what is the path of the file ? Does it belongs to the windows 8 kit sdk ? ( the default one shipped with visual studio 2012 ).

Comment: No. I use the one in `Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include` which I thought was outdated but the latest DX SDK I can download is this version from June 2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=6812). Btw I am writing for / on Windows 7.

Comment: Windowd 8 kits sdk is also for windows 7. And the dx sdk is deprecated, as you saw, the last version is 3 years old. dx sdk is now part of the windows kit. You need to remove all references to it from your project or you will get a lot of problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use w8 kit now. I never knew it was deprecated since dx11 was the latest directx so...